# How can I lock my Firefox passwords and bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, security

How can I lock my Firefox? I want to secure my passwords and bookmarks, so that nobody can access them in my absence.

Comment: Why don't You just lock the session when You away from computer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension [MasterPassword+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/master-password/).

[image]